# ncurses: Why is the RGB color value range from 0 - 1000?

Tags: c, ncurses

The RGB color value range is 0-255 for each value in the RGB triple. Why does ncurses make the range 0-1000 for each value in an RGB triple? Is there a trivial way to translate from the 0-255 range to the 0-1000 range such that colors remain true to the 0-255 range?

Comment: Perhaps [@Thomas Dickey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4518274/thomas-dickey) could answer this question.

Comment: He did in a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43710790/26428).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curses was built *from the ground up* to be terminal-independent, and that *includes* whatever color encoding scheme you wish to use. Some terminals may only provide sixteen fixed colors, some may be grey-scale, some may be strictly black and white and some may provide trillions of colors.

From the [SCO documentation](http://uw714doc.sco.com/en/SDK_charm/_Color_Manipulation.html) (the *original* SCO, not the renamed Caldera that became a pariah of the open source world):

> Like the rest of curses, the color manipulation routines have been designed to be terminal independent. But it must be remembered that the capabilities of terminals vary.

The color mix capability is therefore something that's considered good enough for whatever you can throw at it, allowing a billion different mixtures which can then be mapped to the *actual* capability of whatever terminal you're using.

I, for one, certainly can't tell the difference between `#808080` and `#808081` :-)

If you want to translate the `0-1000` range of Curses to a more "conventional" range, you can do something like:

```
red = red * 51 / 200;  // 51/200 == 255/1000
```

(and ditto for the other color components).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest translation is just to multiply it by a factor of .255:

```
r = r * 0.255
g = g * 0.255
b = b * 0.255
```

As to why that decision was made, I suspect it was completely arbitrary though I don't have any facts to back that up.