# How does ncurses' init_color function translate to traditional rbg colors?

Tags: ncurses

Sorry for the oddly worded title. I'd like to know how the ncurses init_color function maps it's input to colors. Essentially, most developers are used to colors being represented by red, green, and blue on a 0 - 255 scale, but init_color takes an int on a 0 - 1000 scale.

for example:

If I wanted to get the color `(75, 0, 130)` in ncurses, would I call `init_color(COLOR_NAME, 300, 0, 520)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

short:

```
(n) * 1000 / 256
```

which is a little different from your numbers:

```
293 0 508
```

long: That of course assumes that the terminal description is written to match ncurses' [documentation](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_color.3x.html#h3-init_color).  But the assumption is from [X/Open Curses](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/can_change_color.html):

> The **`init_color()`** function redefines colour number color, on terminals that support the redefinition of colours, to have the red, green, and blue intensity components specified by *red*, *green*, and *blue*, respectively. Calling init_color() also changes all occurrences of the specified colour on the screen to the new definition.
>
> The **`color_content()`** function identifies the intensity components of colour number *color*. It stores the red, green, and blue intensity components of this colour in the addresses pointed to by red, green, and blue, respectively.
>
> For both functions, the *color* argument must be in the range from 0 to and including COLORS-1. Valid intensity values range from 0 (no intensity component) up to and including **1000** (maximum intensity in that component).

Comment: [Why 1000?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28401332/ncurses-why-is-the-rgb-color-value-range-from-0-1000)

Comment: It's an arbitrary scale factor chosen long ago in the 1980s by others who did not leave further clues.